# Make input field jquery ui datepicker editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I've scanned trough the documentation but I can't find out how I to get the field to get the datepickers value AND let it be editable using my keyboard numpad. So filling/editing the date without using the datepicker.

I hope my question is clear cause I don't know how the formulate it otherwise.

Comment: Post the code you're using to initialize the date picker.

Comment: I was just so stupid to test it not using numeric values.. Problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

It is already ( see http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ ) editable.

Comment: godd*mn , I'm gonna blame that one to lack of sleep.. :) THX!

Comment: you might like the constrainInput option which only allows the characters in the provided date format (like numbers and forward-slash, etc)